# Entity Framework Core .Include() is filtering the query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1.3 and I am have these two queries:

```
var test = await _unitOfWork.Context.PersonEmail
    .OrderBy(e => e.EmailId)
    .Take(10)
    .Include(e => e.EmailRecord)
    .ToListAsync();
var test2 = await _unitOfWork.Context.PersonEmail
    .OrderBy(e => e.EmailId)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

I was expecting both queries to return 10 results, but for 6 of the items from the `test` query to have `null` for the `EmailRecord` property (since the EmailRecord table does not contain an entry for those particular items). However what actually happens is that the `test` query returns only 4 results, whilst the `test2` query returns the expected 10.

The entities are declared like this:

```
[Table("PersonEmail")]
public class PersonEmail
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Guid EmailId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonId, EmailId")]
    public EmailRecord EmailRecord { get; set; }
}

[Table("EmailRecord")]
public class EmailRecord
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public Guid EmailId { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PersonEmail>().HasKey(x => new { x.PersonId, x.EmailId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmailRecord>().HasKey(x => new { x.PersonId, x.EmailId });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the (improper) relationship configuration.

The way you have defined it

```
[ForeignKey("PersonId, EmailId")]
```

in `PersonEmail` makes it one-to-one relationship with `PersonEmail` being the **dependent** (because of the FK) and `EmailRecord` being the **principal**.

If that was true, then "since the EmailRecord table does not contain an entry for those particular items" simply cannot happen due to the enforced FK constraint. And because of that, EF Core 3.0+ `Include` is generating correctly `inner join`, which should not filter the main set, but in fact does filter it because of the actual data relationship in the database.

To fix it, you have to reflect the actual relationship, which seems to be other way around - one-to-one with principal `PersonEmail` and dependent `EmailRecord`.

Remove the above `[ForeignKey]` attribute and add the following fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonEmail>()
    .HasOne(x => x.EmailRecord)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<EmailRecord>(x => new { x.PersonId, x.EmailId });
```

Now the `Include` will use `left outer join` and won't filter the `PersonEmail` records.

For more info, see [Relationships - One-to-one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#one-to-one) EF Core documentation.